# Why didn't Deadshot kill Batman when he had a chance?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

I'm not sure if I missed something, but I have a feeling there is some inconsistency there.

At the beginning of *Suicide Squad* we find out how important his daughter is for Deadshot. When he met Batman in the alley, she asks her father not to kill him, so for her he sacrifices his freedom. 
But later in the movie, all characters are under Enchantress' spell. Under that spell, they live in their dreams. Harley has a normal family with Mr J. El Diablo's family is alive. And Deadshot killed Batman.

Now, if this was his biggest dream, why he didn't do it when he had a chance in that alley? That vision which he had, when he was under Enchantress' spell indicates killing Batman was more important than being with his daughter, and if his daughter is more important, why was the vision not about her?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because he regrets not killing Batman when he had the chance.

He chose not to fight Batman because his daughter asked. But as a result, he went to prison, where he was no longer able to see his daughter. Even worse, Waller used his daughter as leverage to force him to join the Suicide Squad.

In Deadshot's mind, all of that is Batman's fault. If he had killed Batman instead, his daughter might have been angry at him for a while, but he would still be able to see her, and be part of her life. And eventually she would probably forgive him.

His paradise world, under Enchantress's spell, is for a world in which he killed Batman instead of turning himself in.

Comment: But in this case, should his paradise be about him and his daughter being happy, rather than killing Bat?

Comment: @user902383 People often focus on what they think would make them happy, instead of on actually being happy. There is a famous John Lennon quote: "When I was 5 years old, my mother always told me that happiness was the key to life. When I went to school, they asked me what I wanted to be when I grew up. I wrote down 'happy'. They told me I didn’t understand the assignment, and I told them they didn’t understand life". They probably expected him to write "fireman", "rich", etc. Same here, Deadshot focused on killing the Batman as a way to happiness, instead of focusing on just being happy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why does he not kill Batman in the first place?  Because of his daughter. She begs him not to, and, if he did anyway, it would not be just the death/killing she does not want that she would see, but revealing himself to her as a cold-blooded murderer, which she would carry with her for the rest of her days, that makes him hold off.

Later on, in the movie, Deadshot is done with the mission - doesn't care if they get killed, doesn't care if the world ends, it was all a cynical sham and manipulation anyway. What changes his mind? Finding out his daughter was writing him letters, and that she still cared about him -

> You had these the whole time? You had letters from my daughter the whole time? I'm gonna get you there. And you're gonna end this. I'm gonna carry your ass if I have to. 'Cause this shit is gonna be like a chapter in the Bible. Everybody's gonna know what we did. **And my daughter is gonna know that her daddy is not a piece of shit.**

So, when the Enchantress read their minds and projected their wishes, sure, Batman separated him from his daughter and took away his freedom, so there's resentment there, plus, you know, he is a killer. I didn't see anything in his fantasy where his daughter was there, watching him get his revenge, so, really, there's no contradiction between what went down when he did have the chance, and his fantasy of revenge. If the enchantress sent a fantasy of him having a happy reunion with his daughter, instead, that might just harden his resolve to stop the Enchantress.  Note, also, that he does quickly snap out of it when Diablo tells them it's not real.